# 'Stack.Navigator' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

There is a type issue using react navigation, when use `Stack.Navigation` or `Stack.Group` from `createNativeStackNavigator`

The issue saids that the types dont match with `JSX.element` at the end of the messages is more specific:  `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'`

Whole message:

```
'Stack.Navigator' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<Omit<DefaultRouterOptions<string> & { id?: string | undefined; children: ReactNode; screenListeners?: Partial<...> | ... 1 more ... | undefined; screenOptions?: NativeStackNavigationOptions | ... 1 more ... | undefined; defaultScreenOptions?: NativeStackNavigationOptions | ... 1 mo...' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<Omit<DefaultRouterOptions<string> & { id?: string | undefined; children: ReactNode; screenListeners?: Partial<{ transitionStart: EventListenerCallback<NativeStackNavigationEventMap, "transitionStart">; ... 4 more ...; beforeRemove: EventListenerCallback<...>; }> | ((props: { ...; }) => Partial<...>) | unde...' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<Omit<DefaultRouterOptions<string> & { id?: string | undefined; children: ReactNode; screenListeners?: Partial<{ transitionStart: EventListenerCallback<NativeStackNavigationEventMap, "transitionStart">; ... 4 more ...; beforeRemove: EventListenerCallback<...>; }> | ((props: { ...; }) => Partial<...>) | unde...' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/mrcmesen/Novum/ice-app/plant-maintenance/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)
```

The way to reprocede is just install these versions and run the project.

```
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.1",
"typescript": "^4.6.3"
```

My application still works and I don't have any error in console. I don't know why I have a red line under Stack.Navigator. But when I hover on it, it says that 'Stack.Navigator' cannot be used as a JSX component.

[image]

I also got the same error when using MaterialCommunityIcons

### Update at 12-04-22 *For React-Navigation*

This is a issue related to the version of `@types/react` you need to add this minimum resolution to your project to solve it:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/react": "^17.0.41"
}
```

Reference: [Github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/59765#issuecomment-1092891129)
Credits: [@lucasmds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10547493/lucasmds)

Comment: Do you `npm install` after that or ?

Comment: Slight note: `@types/react 17.0.41` didn't work for me, but `18.0.8` fixed this for me.

Comment: For me `18.0.1` worked

Comment: above 18.X.X fixed this issue for me

Answer (score 36):

You will need to fix the version for `@types/react` package because many react libraries have dependency set as `@types/react : "*",` which will take the latest version of the package. (I suppose they just released version 18)

To do that you can add this in your `package.json`

if you use yarn

```
"resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.43"
  }
```

`$ yarn`

OR in npm

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react": "^17.0.41"
}
```

OR

```
"devDependencie": {
  "@types/react": "18.0.8"
}
```

and run  `$ npm install`

you can also use `resolutions` with [npm-force-resolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions) library

to do that you need to add to the `script` section in `package.json` file

```
"preinstall": "npm install --package-lock-only --ignore-scripts && npx npm-force-resolutions"
```

And then after doing `npm install`

[see github issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/59765#issuecomment-1092891129)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243811/discussion-on-answer-by-yoel-stack-navigator-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component).

Comment: Upgrading to the latest version worked for me.

Comment: It resolves the Navigator component issue but conflicts with type script when npm start command is fired.

Comment: the "resolution" answer fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes, but with npm “resolution” doesn't  work

Answer (score 20):

It's a simple typing error that can be resolved by updating the React typing.

`npm install -D @types/react`

or

`yarn add -D @types/react`

Answer (score 5):

I fix it by updating @types/react up to its 18 version.

actually I'm using "@types/react": "^18.0.9".

To update just do:

```
npm install -D @types/react
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Run yarn why @types/react for Yarn and npm ls @types/react to check
   if there are multiple versions installed and why they are being
   installed
2. add "resolutions": { "@types/react": "~17.0.21"} or another version
   compatible with react-native in package.json
3. run 'yarn install' or npm i

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem at the **expo** and nothing resolved it, even with resolutions.
Because the expo always warned `It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but don't have the required dependencies installed. Would you like to install @types/react`

Then I found this solution, using version 18.0.0 inside resolutions. Add this to package.json:

```json
"resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "18.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: Add this to `package.json` resolved the error for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `"expo": "~45.0.0"`. After installing [react native elements](https://reactnativeelements.com/)  the error comes up. As [@yoel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71816203/7178860) said

> You will need to fix the version for *@types/react* package because many react libraries have dependency set as *@types/react: "*"*, which will take the *latest version of the package*

The problem is `@types/x: "*"` which in my case is **@types/react-native: "*"**. So I added this `resolutions`. I took the *versions* by looking at my `devDependencies`.

like this and everything works fine:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.67.6",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.67.6"
  }
```