# How to change version of react typescript typings that expo (react native) requires?

Tags: react-native, expo

Regarding react-native + expo, I would like to use latest @type/react in order to resolve typing issues (i.e. 'MaterialIcons' cannot be used as a JSX component), but `expo start` always require I install the typescript libraries and then proceeds to insist they be an older version (17.0.21). Why? How can I either ignore this behaviour (btw. answering with 'n' ends the startup and directs to either install the typescript requirements or clean the config of typescript refs -- ok `expo` thanks for nothing!)

The problem that I was resolving with `@types/react` is detailed here: ['Stack.Navigator' cannot be used as a JSX component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71816116/stack-navigator-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component)

Answer (score 0):

update to  "@types/react": "~18.0.12" ( fix for eslint )
but you cant run project

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into this and after some research I found this github [comment](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17782#issuecomment-1153845928) from the expo repo. Which made think about this resolutions [fix](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4329#issuecomment-1131845172).

In my yarn.lock I have two versions 17.0.21 and 17.0.47, and in my package.json I point to 17.0.21

```
resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21"
  },
```

- Ran yarn once again
- Opened the VSCode Command Palette -> Typescript:
  Reload project

No problems with eslint and was able to run the project.